# Append multiple row instead of single row from json

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have script to copy json data to google sheet, bus Is there any way to append multiple rows instead of single row

Can anybody explain how i change this script ? Thanks

```
function doPost(request = {}) {
  const { parameter, postData: { contents, type } = {} } = request; //request data
  const { dataReq = {} } = JSON.parse(contents); //content
  const { fname = {} } = JSON.parse(contents); //function name

  const response = {
    status: "function not found: " + fname, // prepare response in function not found
    data2: dataReq
  }
  switch (fname) { //function selection
    case 'pasteData':
      var output = JSON.stringify(pasteDAta(dataReq)) //call function with data from request
      break
    default:
      var output = JSON.stringify(response)
      break
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); //response to frontend
}
function pasteDAta(dataReq) {
  const id = '1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0'; //id of Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //sheet
  var headings = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0]; //Headers
  var i = 0 //to test the times that efectively adds rows the forEach function
  
  dataReq.forEach((a) => { //go trought every item on dataReq as 'a'
    let holder = []; //to steore temp the elements
    for (x in headings) { //to add in order of Headers on sheet
      let output = (headings[x] in a) ? a[headings[x]] : ''; //if exist add, if not empty
      holder.push(output); //add to holder
    }
    sheet.appendRow(holder); //put holder(order data) on sheet
    i += 1 //to test the times
  });
  return "Numbers of sheets added: "+i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var i = 0 //to test the times that efectively adds rows the forEach function

dataReq.forEach((a) => { //go trought every item on dataReq as 'a'
  let holder = []; //to steore temp the elements
  for (x in headings) { //to add in order of Headers on sheet
    let output = (headings[x] in a) ? a[headings[x]] : ''; //if exist add, if not empty
    holder.push(output); //add to holder
  }
  sheet.appendRow(holder); //put holder(order data) on sheet
  i += 1 //to test the times
});
return "Numbers of sheets added: "+i;
```

#### To:

```
var values = dataReq.map((a) => {
  let holder = [];
  for (x in headings) {
    let output = (headings[x] in a) ? a[headings[x]] : '';
    holder.push(output);
  }
  return holder;
});
var len = values.length;
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, len, values[0].length).setValues(values);
return "Numbers of sheets added: " + len;
```

- In this modification, `map` is used instead of `forEach`. And, a 2-dimensional array is returned. This array is appended to the sheet using `setValues`.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- If this modification was not the direct solution to your issue, when you provide the sample value of `dataReq`, I think that it will help to think of the modification points.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thanks, It is working for me. This work around is excellent and very easy.